# How to use placeholder with intl.formatMessage

Tags: reactjs, react-intl

I'm trying to use `react-intl` to add localization to my app. Like this

```
<FormattedHTMLMessage id="marker.title" values={{
        name: (b.name !== null ? b.name : "Bench"),
        seats: Tools.showValue(b.seats),
        material: Tools.showValue(b.material),
        color: Tools.getColorNameFromInt(b.color),
        lat: b.lat,
        lng: b.lng,
    }}/>
```

But I need a string so I tried this

```
const title = this.props.intl.formatMessage({
    id: "marker.title",
    values: {
        name: (b.name !== null ? b.name : "Bench"),
        seats: Tools.showValue(b.seats),
        material: Tools.showValue(b.material),
        color: Tools.getColorNameFromInt(b.color),
        lat: b.lat,
        lng: b.lng,
    }
});
```

and I get the following error message:

```
Error: The intl string context variable 'name' was not provided to the string '{name}<br/>Seats: {seats}<br/>Material: {material}<br/>Color: {color}<br/>Location: {lat} / {lng}'
```

`en.json`

```
{
  "marker.title": "{name}<br/>Seats: {seats}<br/>Material: {material}<br/>Color: {color}<br/>Location: {lat} / {lng}"
}
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Figured it out if you do it like this it will work

```
this.props.intl.formatMessage({id: "marker.title"}, {
                name: (b.name !== null ? b.name : "Bench"),
                seats: Tools.showValue(b.seats, this.props.intl),
                material: Tools.showValue(b.material, this.props.intl),
                color: Tools.getColorNameFromInt(b.color, this.props.intl),
                lat: b.lat,
                lng: b.lng,
            });
```

Let's hope I find this answer again when I'm stuck at this thing again.